# how to reload storyboard when change localization swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, localization, uistoryboard

I create one project and use localization in it.

I use this method : [language_manager](https://github.com/maximbilan/ios_language_manager) in my project and change syntax to swift by self.

now when click in language my storyboard not changing :
[image]

this is my code :

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var data = [AnyObject]()

    @IBOutlet weak var label1 : UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tables : UITableView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.data = LanguageManager.languageStrings()
        self.label1.text = NSLocalizedString("Happy New Year", comment: "")
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}

extension ViewController : UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        //print("\(ELanguage.Count)")
        return 4
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 50
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0.01
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0.01
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellIdentifier")
        let cell : UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellIdentifier")!
        cell.textLabel?.text = (self.data[indexPath.row] as! String)
        if indexPath.row == LanguageManager.currentLanguageIndex() {
            cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
        } else {
            cell.accessoryType = .None
        }
        return cell

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

        LanguageManager.saveLanguageByIndex(indexPath.row)
        self.tables.reloadData()
        self.reloadRootViewController()
    }

    func reloadRootViewController() {

        let delegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let storyString = "Main"
        let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: storyString, bundle: nil)
        delegate.window?.rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try reloading your storyboard and your root view controller:

```
- (void)reloadRootViewController
    {
        AppDelegate *delegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
        NSString *storyboardName = @"Main";
        UIStoryboard *storybaord = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle:nil];
        delegate.window.rootViewController = [storybaord instantiateInitialViewController];
}
```